# light bulb recommendations for my youtube channel setup

Tags: lighting

[image]
I have some softboxes that use light bulbs. My goal is to have a youtube video studio.

I want to know what bulb to use and if I can use LEDs. Hopefully LEDs that change temperature colour.

Thanks!